# C# Time Subtraction With a Discord Bot

Tags: c#, datetime, time, subtraction, discord.net

I'm making a funny discord bot that finds the next 4:20 on the clock, whether it's AM or PM, and tells you how long until 4:20. My code is working perfectly until an hour before 4:20 and then it skips ahead and tells how long until the next 4:20 instead of showing "0 hours 59 minutes". I'm thinking that there may be an issue with how I'm formatting the time output but I'm very new to C# and how no idea how to fix it. I have included my code and also a screenshot of the current output. In the screenshot the bot is also a minute off but I've since then figured out how to fix that. I know the code isn't the most efficient or clean but again, I'm very new to programming.

[image: screenshot of bot output]

```
//Finds next 4:20 on the clock
[Command("420")]
public async Task WeedMinute()
{
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now; //Current time
    DateTime weedMinuteMorning = Convert.ToDateTime("4:21:00"); //4:20am
    DateTime weedMinuteEvening = Convert.ToDateTime("16:21:00"); //4:20pm

    string weedMinutePM = "16:21:00"; //These variables are used in subtraction
    string weedMinuteAM = "4:21:00";


    if (currentTime <= weedMinuteEvening)
    {
        //chooseMorningEvening is the output time string
        DateTime chooseMorningEvening = (DateTime.Parse(weedMinutePM).Subtract(currentTime.TimeOfDay));

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("The next weed minute will happen in " + chooseMorningEvening.ToString(@"hh") + " hours " + chooseMorningEvening.ToString(@"mm") + " minutes.");
    }
    else if (currentTime >= weedMinuteMorning)
    {
        //chooseMorningEvening is the output time string
        DateTime chooseMorningEvening = (DateTime.Parse(weedMinuteAM).Subtract(currentTime.TimeOfDay));

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("The next weed minute will happen in " + chooseMorningEvening.ToString(@"hh") + " hours " + chooseMorningEvening.ToString(@"mm") + " minutes.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's enought to just remove TimeOfDay from currentTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it does not handle all the cases that can occur (there are three):

- time is between 00:00:00 and 04:20:00 => calculate time to 04:20:00
- time is between 04:20:00 and 16:20:00 => calculate time to 16:20:00
- time is after 16:20:00 => calculate time to 04:20:00, next day.

You can simplify this a little if you observe that the time till your next toke should always be between 0 and 12 hours. So, if you just take the time until 16:20, if it is greater than 12 hours then you must be up before 04:20 and you can subtract 12 hours. If the time is less than 0 (that is, negative) then you must be later than 16:20 so you just add 12 hours. In code this looks like this:

```
    public static TimeSpan CalculateTimeToWeed(DateTime from)
    {
        DateTime weedTime = Convert.ToDateTime("16:20:00");
        TimeSpan twelveHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(12.0);

        TimeSpan timeToWeed = weedTime - from;
        double totalHours = timeToWeed.TotalHours;
        if (totalHours > 12.0)
        {
            timeToWeed -= twelveHours;
        }
        else if (totalHours < 0.0)
        {
            timeToWeed += twelveHours;
        }
        return timeToWeed;
    }
```

and you would integrate it into your Discord bot as follows:

```
    [Command("420")]
    public async Task WeedMinute()
    {
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now; 
        TimeSpan timeToWeed = CalculateTimeToWeed(currentTime);
        string message = "The next weed minute will happen in " + timeToWeed.ToString("hh' hours 'mm'  minutes.'");
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(message);
    }
```

You could cut down the number of lines in this, but having these temporary variable makes thing easier to debug. You can check while stepping through with a debugger that `currentTime` is what you expect and `timeToWeed` makes sense and so on.

Breaking the code into two functions also has a number of advantages:

- You can test the time calculation independent of the bot
- The code is much clearer, you are not mixing up communication code with calculation code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a DateTime.Compare function which can be used here to fix the error as below

```
            //DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now; //Current time
            DateTime currentTime = Convert.ToDateTime("3:22:00");  // An example time for 0 hours and 59 mins
            DateTime weedMinuteMorning = Convert.ToDateTime("4:21:00"); //4:20am
            DateTime weedMinuteEvening = Convert.ToDateTime("16:21:00"); //4:20pm

            string weedMinutePM = "16:21:00"; //These variables are used in subtraction
            string weedMinuteAM = "4:21:00";

            if(currentTime.CompareTo(weedMinuteMorning) < 1)  //less than or same as Morning 4:20 am
            {
                var chooseMorningEvening = weedMinuteMorning - currentTime;
                string m = "The next weed minute will happen in " + chooseMorningEvening.Hours + " hours " + chooseMorningEvening.Minutes + " minutes.";
            }
            else
            {
                var chooseMorningEvening = weedMinuteEvening - currentTime;
                string m = "The next weed minute will happen in " + chooseMorningEvening.Hours + " hours " + chooseMorningEvening.Minutes + " minutes.";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting the time output seem ok, just for better formats see [Custom TimeSpan format strings.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings?view=netcore-3.1)

Your code have three problem:
 1. If Conditions

```
if (currentTime <= weedMinuteEvening)
{
    //this condition is true from 00:00:00 to 16:21:01 so for dates less than 4:21:00
    //you get incorrect output, and next condition execute just for dates greater than 16:21:00.
    ...
}
else if (currentTime >= weedMinuteMorning)
{
   //This code execute only for dates greater than 16:21:00.
    ...
}
```

2. As Adam suggested you must remove `.TimeOfDay` from `currentTime` but this not enough.
3. You must handle dates grater than 16:21:00

So i hope this code work for you:

```
[Command("420")]
public async Task WeedMinute()
{
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now; //Current time
    DateTime weedMinuteMorning = Convert.ToDateTime("4:21:00"); //4:20am
    DateTime weedMinuteEvening = Convert.ToDateTime("16:21:00"); //4:20pm

    //I removed These variables, Don't need to parse same DateTime again. change it as you wish
    //string weedMinutePM = "16:21:00";
    //string weedMinuteAM = "4:21:00";

    if (currentTime <= weedMinuteMorning)
    {
        TimeSpan timeSpan = weedMinuteMorning.Subtract(currentTime);

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("The next weed minute will happen in " + timeSpan.ToString("hh' hours 'mm'  minutes.'"));
    }
    else if (currentTime <= weedMinuteEvening)
    {
        TimeSpan timeSpan = weedMinuteEvening.Subtract(currentTime);

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("The next weed minute will happen in " + timeSpan.ToString("hh' hours 'mm'  minutes.'"));
    }
    else
    {
        //To handle dates greater than 16:21:00, we must calculate hours
        //remaining until 4:20 next day.
        weedMinuteMorning = weedMinuteMorning.AddDays(1);
        TimeSpan timeSpan = weedMinuteMorning.Subtract(currentTime);

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("The next weed minute will happen in " + timeSpan.ToString("hh' hours 'mm'  minutes.'"));

    }
}
```